# Looking for a bound on a contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'm looking for an estimate of this contour integral

$$\left|\,\int_{\gamma}\,\left(\,1+\log^2(u)\,\right)^a\,du\,\right|$$

where parammeter $a\in\mathbb{C}$ and the path $\gamma$ is the circle with center $b$ and radius $b$, that is, $\gamma=\{\,u \,;\,|u-b|=b\,\}$ with $ 0.5\leq b<0.8.$

Since its calculation is difficult, it would be enough to find a bound. With the classical parameterization

$$\left|\,\int_{\gamma}\,\left(\,1+\log^2(u)\,\right)^a\,du\,\right|\leq\,b\,\int_0^{2\pi}\left|\,\left(\,1+\log^2(b+be^{i\,x})\,\right)^{\,a}\,\right|\,dx$$

Any help will be wellcome.

**Edit_1**:
We can split
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\left|\,\left(\,1+\log^2(b+be^{i\,x})\,\right)^{\,a}\,\right|\,dx=\int_0^{\pi}\left|\,\left(\,1+\log^2(b+be^{i\,x})\,\right)^{\,a}\,\right|\,dx+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\left|\,\left(\,1+\log^2(b+be^{i\,x})\,\right)^{\,a}\,\right|\,dx$$

and after a chenge of variable $x-\pi\to y $ we obtain two similar integrals

$$\int_0^{\pi}\left|\,\left(\,1+\log^2(b+be^{i\,x})\,\right)^{\,a}\,\right|\,dx+\int_0^{\pi}\left|\,\left(\,1+\log^2(b-be^{i\,x})\,\right)^{\,a}\,\right|\,dx$$

***The question was solved by Szeto below.***

**Edit_2**: Now, it's possible to find $\int_0^{2\pi}\left|\,\left(\,1+\log^2(b+be^{i\,x})\,\right)^{\,a}\,\right|\,dx$ ?

May be with a change of variable like $b+be^{i\,x}\to e^y$ ?

Comment: Note that the contour goes through $0$, and $\log(0)$ is undefined.  However, you can deal with it as an improper integral.

Comment: Yes, it's true. I think this improper integral is convergent.

Comment: And what is $a?$

Comment: $a$ is any complex number: $a\in\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Not a lot of deep complex analysis is required to answer the question, basically all you need is understanding of $log$ and complex exponents. You want to see how to show the integral is finite?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the contour does not enclose any branch cuts, then

> Claim: $$I:=\text{PV}\,\int_{\gamma}\,\left(\,1+\log^2(u)\,\right)^a\,du=0$$

Proof:

Consider $\Gamma(\epsilon)$, which is the boundary of $\{z~|~|z-b|=b\}\setminus\{z~|~|z|=\epsilon\}$.

Let $\Gamma(\epsilon)=\Gamma_1(\epsilon)\cup\Gamma_2(\epsilon)$, where $\Gamma_1(\epsilon)$ is the circular contour with a bit removed at the origin, and $\Gamma_2(\epsilon)$ is the tiny detour around origin.

By definition, $\displaystyle{I=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\Gamma_1(\epsilon)}\left(\,1+\log^2(u)\,\right)^a\,du}$

1.

Recognize that your contour does not enclose any branch points (the branch point of taking to the power of $a$ is at $e^{\pm i}$, which requires $b>\frac1{2\cos 1}\approx 0.9$ to enclose it) , nor singularities.

By Cauchy's theorem,
$$\oint_{\Gamma(\epsilon)}\left(\,1+\log^2(u)\,\right)^a\,du=0$$ for every $\epsilon>0$.

2.

Let $a=p+iq$.

We observe that, for some $c\in[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2]$, 
$$|(1+\log^2(\epsilon e^{ic}))^a|=\left((1-c^2+\log^2\epsilon)^2+4c^2\log^2\epsilon\right)^{p/2}e^{-q\theta}$$ where $|\theta|$ is bounded by some constant $M$.

Secondly,
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\int_{\Gamma_2(\epsilon)}\left(\,1+\log^2(u)\,\right)^a\,du\right| 
&\le \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\pi/2}^{-\pi/2}|\left(\,1+\log^2(\epsilon e^{it})\,\right)^a i\epsilon e^{it}|dt \\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\pi/2}^{-\pi/2}|\left(\,1+\log^2(\epsilon e^{it})\,\right)^a |\epsilon dt \\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\pi\cdot\epsilon |(1+\log^2(\epsilon e^{ic}))^a| \qquad{(1)} \\
&\le\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\pi\cdot\epsilon \left((1-c^2+\log^2\epsilon)^2+4c^2\log^2\epsilon\right)^{p/2}e^{|q|M} \\
&=0
\end{align}
$$
$(1)$: By mean value theorem for integral, $c\in[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2]$.

Therefore,
$$\begin{align}
I
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\Gamma_1(\epsilon)}\left(\,1+\log^2(u)\,\right)^a\,du \\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\oint_{\Gamma(\epsilon)}\left(\,1+\log^2(u)\,\right)^a\,du-\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\int_{\Gamma_2(\epsilon)}\left(\,1+\log^2(u)\,\right)^a\,du \\
&=0-0 \\
&=0
\end{align}
$$

Q.E.D.

Comment: Many Thanks !!!

Comment: You think it's possible to find $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left|\,\left(\,1+\log^2(b+be^{i\,x})\,\right)^{\,a}\,\right|\,dx$ ?

Comment: @popi Quite messy, but I will try it later.

Comment: @popi If $a$ is real then it might be doable.

Comment: Unfortunately, $a$ is complex. In any way, it could be interesting.